# How to update the members of objects in the array constructed from another class?

Tags: c++, class, object, oop, parameter-passing

I have 2 separate classes in C++,which are `Algorithms` class and `Student` class, each of have the following members and methods.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define MAX  10
class Student {
private:
   int ID;
   string name;
   string surname;
   int quiz_scores[4];

public:
   Student()
   {
      ID = 0;
      name = "" ;
      surname = "";
      quiz_scores[4] = {0};
   }
   void setID(int ID_set);
   int getID();
   void setName(string name_set);
   string getName();
   void setSurName(string surname_set);
   string getSurName();
   void setQuizScores(int* quizscores);
   const int* getQuizScores() const;
};
```

and `Algorithms` class as follows:

```
class Algorithms{
   private:
      Student students[MAX];
      int num =0 ; // The current number of students in the course, initially 0.
      float weightQ;
      float weightHW;
      float weightF;

   public:
      Algorithms()
      {
         students[num] = {};
         weightQ = 0.3;
         weightHW = 0.3;
         weightF = 0.4;

      }
      int getNum(); // Returns how many students are in the course
      void addNewStudent(Student new_student);
```

And here is the methods declerations of `Student` class and `Algorithms` class respectively.

```
// Method declerations for the class Student

void Student :: setID(int ID_set){
   ID = ID_set;
}
int Student :: getID(){
   return ID;
}
void Student :: setName(string name_set){
   name = name_set;
}
string Student :: getName(){
   return name;
}
void Student :: setSurName(string surname_set){
   surname = surname_set;
}
string Student :: getSurName(){
   return surname;
}
void Student :: setQuizScores(int* quizscores){
   for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
      quiz_scores[i] = quizscores[i];
   }
}
const int* Student :: getQuizScores() const {
   return quiz_scores;   }

// Method declerations for the class Algorithms

int Algorithms:: getNum(){
   return num;
}
void Algorithms :: addNewStudent(Student new_student){
   students[num] = new_student ;
   num = num + 1;
}
void Algorithms :: updateWeights(float weightQ_update, float weightHW_update, float weightF_update){
            weightQ = weightQ_update;
            weightHW = weightHW_update;
            weightF = weightF_update; 
}
void Algorithms :: getStudentInfo(int ID_given, Algorithms &algorithms){
   for(int i = 0; i<MAX; i++){
      if(ID_given == students[i].getID()){
         cout << "Student Name & Surname : " << students[i].getName() << " " << students[i].getSurName()<<"\n";
         cout << "Quiz results :" <<  students[i].getQuizScores();
      }
   } 
}
```

I have also user-interface in the `main`. It calls the following functions

```
void addNewStudent(int ID, string name, string surname, Algorithms &algorithms){
    Student student;
    student.setID(ID);
    student.setName(name);
    student.setSurName(surname);                                  
    algorithms.addNewStudent(student);
 }
   
 void showStudent(int ID, Algorithms &algorithms){
    algorithms.getStudentInfo(ID, algorithms);
 }
```

Both work properly with the code in `main` as below

```
int main(){
   Algorithms ECE101;
   int x;
   int ID;
   string name, surname;

   string option_1 = "1) Add a student ";
   string option_2 = "2) Search a student by ID";
   string option_3 = "3) Change a student’s score";

   cout << "Welcome to the ECE101 Classroom Interface"<<"\n";
   cout << "Choose your option\n";
   cin >> x;

    do {
        if (x == 1) {
            cout << "Enter the student ID ";
            cin >> ID;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Enter the student name ";
            cin >> name;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Enter the student surname " ;
            cin >> surname;
            addNewStudent(ID, name, surname, ECE101);
        }
        else if (x==2){
            cout << "Enter the student ID\n";
            cin >> ID;
            showStudent(ID, ECE101);
        }
        else {
           int quiz_grades[4];
           cout << "Enter the student ID";
           cin >> ID;
           cout << endl;
           cout << "Enter the quiz grades" << endl;
           for (int i = 0 ; i<4 ; i++) {
              cin >> quiz_grades[i];
           }
           changeStudentScores(ID, quiz_grades);
        }
```

The problem here comes from   `changeStudentScores(ID, quiz_grades, ECE101)`
What I want to do is the program should take the array of 4 numbers(corresponds to the quiz grades) and set to the student, whose ID's given by the user. (Of course, firstly the student should be added to the course by the option 1) BUT, I could not pass the array to the  `changeStudentScores` , where it is implemented by

```
void changeStudentScores(int ID, int* quizscores ){
    // Problem occurs here, creating new students object is not so logical, but I tried.
    Student student;
    student.setID(ID);
    student.setQuizScores();
    // I just try to pass the quiz grades writing by the user to the set method, which set quiz grades to the students.
```

After choose the option 2 which shows the information about the students given the ID, I see the correct name and surname, but I could not update the quiz grades.

**RESTRICTIONS**:

- There should be no other method and data members other than the written methods and data members.
- But we can implement additional methods and functions (but not class data
  members)
- `getStudentInfo(int ID_given, Algorithms &algorithms)` function must return student information given ID, but my implementation I could use with `void`

  **QUESTIONS**:
- How can I implement correctly the `changeStudentScores` function so that the user can update the existing student quiz score?
- My `getStudentInfo(int ID_given, Algorithms &algorithms)` function returns nothing that I can use for getting information. So need to be returned the student information, so the return type must not be `void`.
- What is the general idea behind updating the members of the objects, which are used in another class with some data structure(here is array.)

Comment: What you did in `addNewStudent` to pass in the `Algorithms` instance seems like the right place to start. Then adding new function to `Algorithms` to find and return a reference to the requested in `students` will give you a tool to get access to the necessary `Student`.

Comment: @user4581301 Consider it is like programming assignment, and there are some restrictions, which one of them is do not use other methods inside the classes.

Comment: Please add the restrictions to the question.

Comment: @user4581301 Added, thank you!

Comment: Afraid you're screwed then. There is no way to update the contents of `students` or provide access to `students` to do the updating outside of `Algorithms` via the interface provided by `Algorithms`.

Comment: @user4581301 How about if we define global objects?

Comment: Global variables suck. They cause more problems than they solve. As soon as you make a variable global you expose yourself to nastiness like the [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof) and the variable can be modified at any point in your code at any time, meaning everything in your program could have side effects you need to trace while debugging.

Comment: That said, what would you make global?

Comment: @user4581301 So, there is no way of accessing the membere of objects, whose forms an member of another class with array?

Comment: When a member is `private` the only ways allowed by the language to access the member is through the class. If the class's interface has no methods that provide access, you have to cheat or co-opt part of the interface to force it to break encapsulation. And if you have to break encapsulation, why encapsulate in the first place?  I think you should have a chat with your instructor. Odds are you are misinterpreting an instruction.

Comment: @user4581301 Actually, yes. For, `getStudentInfo` method in the `Algorithms`, it is written that **returns a student information given ID**. BUT I returning nothing here. So, I am editing the `getStudentInfo` part in the question. But it is still a problem, how can I return the student informations in the `getStudentInfo` ?

Comment: @user4581301. Now the problem is updated.

Comment: `void Algorithms :: getStudentInfo(int ID_given, Algorithms &algorithms)` makes little sense as a prototype. If it is a non-`static` member function, passing in `algorithms` is pointless. Member functions know the object they've been invoked upon. If it is a `static` function and needs a `Algorithms` instance, it should probably be a member function. and you can't return a `Student` instance with a `void` function. Please discuss the assignment with your instructor. I don't think we can assist you here; the assignment as you've presented it makes no sense.